# How do I subclass the TextCellEditor of Slickgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

How do I subclass the TextCellEditor of [Slickgrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki)?

I want to style the editors used in slickgrid using the [uniform library](http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform/); to do so I need to call

```
$("input, textarea, select, button").uniform();
```

after the html is generated; in other words after the editor object's init function is called; Currently I just copy the entire editor source code and add that line just before the end of the init function. I just seems non elegant.

edit:

to be clear to people unfamiliar with slickgrid, here is the code:

```
var myTextCellEditor = function(args) {
        var $input;
        var defaultValue;
        var scope = this;

        this.init = function() {
            $input = $("<INPUT type=text class='editor-text' />")
                .appendTo(args.container)
                .bind("keydown.nav", function(e) {
                    if (e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.LEFT || e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.RIGHT) {
                        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    }
                })
                .focus()
                .select();

                $input.uniform();
        };

        this.destroy = function() {
            $input.remove();
        };

        this.focus = function() {
            $input.focus();
        };

        this.loadValue = function(item) {
            defaultValue = item[args.column.field] || "";
            $input.val(defaultValue);
            $input[0].defaultValue = defaultValue;
            $input.select();
        };

        this.serializeValue = function() {
            return $input.val();
        };

        this.applyValue = function(item,state) {
            item[args.column.field] = state;
        };

        this.isValueChanged = function() {
            return (!($input.val() == "" && defaultValue == null)) && ($input.val() != defaultValue);
        };

        this.validate = function() {
            if (args.column.validator) {
                var validationResults = args.column.validator($input.val());
                if (!validationResults.valid)
                    return validationResults;
            }

            return {
                valid: true,
                msg: null
            };
        };

        this.init();
    }
```

Where **$input.uniform();** is the only line that is different from the default TextCellEditor.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind a .ready() event to the generated html content by class using .live() so it applies to all future content, not just content present in the initial DOM.

So...

```
$('.classOfSlickGrid').live('ready', function() {
    $("input, textarea, select, button").uniform();
}
```

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work; Maybe because the DOM ready event doesn't fire a second time after the DOM changed?