# SlickGrid - change the style of the input Slick.Editors

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, slickgrid

How can I change the style of the input called by the Slick.Editor.Text?
I tried with: [How do I subclass the TextCellEditor of Slickgrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557659/how-do-i-subclass-the-textcelleditor-of-slickgrid)
but I'm not using uniform and it doesn't work, the table dissapears like an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in an example but the class is not on the core.
You must add (and/or change) the following style to your css:
For eg, I added the size property and set it to 10px

```
/* Slick.Editors.Text, Slick.Editors.Date */
input.editor-text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: transparent;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  size:10px;

}
```